# GS3 Screen Turns Off before timeout

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, screen-timeout

I have an unrooted Galaxy S3, with official Samsung Android 4.1.2 ROM.

Yesterday the device just started to turn of the screen **without locking** the phone and before **screen timeout**, and it just won't stop !!!

I tried to change the screen timeout duration, didn't work, I stopped the Galaxy S3 feature **smart stay** and set it back on again and again and it's not working, I googled this problem and I can't find anything related..

I only have one option to do, and I wish I'm wrong, which is to do a **factory data reset**

I'm afraid that there might be a problem in the **power button**, again I hope I'm wrong.

Please any help is very much appreciated ..

Comment: Have you installed any automation tools such as Tasker, AutomateIt or Llama? I know that certain automation tools make setting or resetting the Display Timeout an easy example of an automation capability.

Comment: I did install a game "Real Racing 3", when I noticed the problem I removed the game.
I doubt that the game has caused the problem, because it's trusted and free in play store.